Throw exception when trying to put a number on a float that will be rounded and lose precision
I need to process a CSV. The users define if a column has floats or doubles. The thing is, sometimes they put doubles in a float column, and after it rounds the values and the users only find out later.
I'd like to not let this behaviour happen if it's at all possible.
So, if we try to store a number too big on a float, it doesn't round it but instead throws an exception.
I'm aware that there are some numbers that cannot be represented correctly like when we do 0.1 + 0.2, this is not what I'm trying to avoid.
I've considered storing everything on a BigDecimal, but currently that has too much impact on the codebase so I'd prefer to avoid it for now.
Edit:
I'm aware there are rounding errors. But assuming the systems are using IEEE 754 floats or doubles, the representation is the same. So a "0.25" float in a system is going to continue to have the same rounding error after imported.

Will it be enough to check number of digits in your input?

You don’t have to store BigDecimals, just create one and compare against the largest float, then throw an exception.

@Sweeper that was my first inclination. Just not sure if that's the fastest way to compare it and the CSVs might have millions of rows.

@talexmovedtoCodidact Wouldn't this fail to catch some rounding cases that just change the last significant digit?

I don’t know. Test it out yourself.

You need to be clear about what your end goal is. Because if you just want to catch misplaced data this strategy won't do it. Wrong data can accidentally have correct precision.

how you know if the entered number is a float or a double?

@user85421 I don't. The user selects the type. But if they put a number too big by mistake or not understanding how floats/doubles work, I want to return an error.

@Sweeper how would I test if this is the fastest way if this is the only way I'm considering?

You don't need the fastest way, do you? Measure whether the performance is enough for your use case.

Your question doesn't make sense. What does 'I do not want rounding errors, but, also, 0.3 is fine' mean? I think you misunderstand a few things. Everything has rounding errors if you use float or double math. The only things that double/float can store without any loss is anything that can be expressed as X/2^Y where X can be whatever. So, 5/8ths can be stored perfectly (because 8 is 2*2*2). Think about decimal. The same thing happens there, except there it's X/(2^Y*5^Z) (because 2 and 5 are the divisors of 10, and decimal = base 10).

... or actually, not even all of those. There are limits on both X and Y for numbers of the form X/2^Y than can be represented exactly as double or float.

If the user entered “0.25”, you cannot know whether they intended a float or a double, as 0.25 is representable in both. If the user entered “0.3”, you cannot know whether they intended a float or a double, as 0.3 is representable in neither. There is no ideal rule that will determine what the user is thinking.

You could try some heuristic like, if it has seven significant digits (including trailing zeroes for this purpose) or fewer, it is a float. But that will not work. If the user wants ¼ in a double, will you compel them to enter “0.25000000” to show they meant a double? And some float values require more than seven digits to represent exactly.

@Sweeper I was hoping for a "turn off casting" kind of solution :) Thanks for your input.

How are they "putting doubles" into a float column? Like you say, if they "enter" 0.1 then there is inherent error. What is an erroneous input for a float? Is it only when the value is too large? You could perform the calculation using double then round to float and complain/warn if there is too much error. From a design standpoint, why use float at all?

@matt A value too big is for instance 16,777,217.
Indeed just using doubles might help and I'm considering that too. The thing is, users can also try to put big longs inside of doubles that don't fit. Basically using what you said but using BigDecimal instead of double should help doing the check, like Sweeper mentioned.

Yes, that would give you the most freedom. You can get the exact input value, then determine if it fits withing the desired datatype. I think what you could do to make this a good question is to include sample inputs and the expected outputs. Such as Double <-> Float there is Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MIN_VALUE (which is the smallest representable size not the largest negative value.) Long values are contained within Double range, so I'm assuming you mean when you lose precision?

How is the CSV produced? If it's created from an Excel spreadsheet, then everything is Double as that's how Excel stores all numeric cells. In that case, just treat everything as Double yourself.

@k314159 we can't ensure where the CSVs come from. That is why the users must set the types, because they are not always the same.

This is what I came up with. Didn't test much yet and need to check if it makes more sense BigDcimal compareTo or equals. I got the limits from this question.
import java.math.BigDecimal;

static boolean isRounded(String strNumber) {
float f = Float.parseFloat(strNumber);
BigDecimal bdf = BigDecimal.valueOf(f);
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(strNumber);

// return bd.equals(bdf);
return bd.compareTo(bdf) != 0;
}

String ok = "16777216";
String nok = "16777217";
System.out.println("is rounded " + isRounded(ok)); // false
System.out.println("is rounded " + isRounded(nok)); // true


The problem is this, consider 0.1. That will get truncated for a Float, but it doesn't get truncated for a BigDecimal. I would say your test isn't quite complete. Also float only contains a subset of int so you could have a value that is less than 16777216 but also not "rounded"

Yeah, was just finding the 0.1 issue. Also, want to check Float.MAX_VALUE.
